# Adding PHP interpreter to PATH

Tags: php, windows, path

I add to global variable `PATH` the path of the folder that contain `php.exe` on a Windows machine (Windows U7 x64). But when I type in the console:

> php -v

I'm getting:

> 'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

And if I type:

> php.exe -v

It works:

> PHP 5.5.10 (cli) (built: Mar May 2014 14:49:07) Copyright (c)
>   1997-2014 The PHP Group Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014
>   Zend Technologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment variable **PATH** contains the list of folders to search for an application separated by semi-colons.

The environment variable **PATHEXT** contains also separated by semi-colons the file extensions valid for applications on search for an application if file name of application is specified on command line or in a batch file without file extension.

It looks like on your computer **PATHEXT** is not correct defined. Standard on Windows is:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH
```

Entering in a command prompt window `set path` displays **PATH** and **PATHEXT**.

See also the remarks section on Microsoft documentation of command [start](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491005.aspx).